# Do I must own a domain when I publish an android app to Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

When I create an android app with Android Studio, the system will create a build.gradle file, and I should to set a namespace such as `com.mydata.soundmeter` for my project.

I know the namespace  `com.mydata.soundmeter` is based domain `mydata.com` in order to keep the app uniqueness when I publish the app to Google Play.

Do I must own the domain `mydata.com` when I publish the app to Google Play?

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdk 32
    flavorDimensions "default"
    namespace 'com.mydata.soundmeter'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydata.soundmeter"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.05"     
    }

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.mydata.soundmeter"
        }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a must as it helps uniquely identify your app. as described here [https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9972781?hl=en#:~:text=You%20can%20find%20an%20app's,example](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9972781?hl=en#:%7E:text=You%20can%20find%20an%20app%27s,example).

However, the name will help users identify your app.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I must own the domain mydata.com when I publish the app to Google Play?

From a legal standpoint? No, unless there are laws in your jurisdiction which somehow cover this case.

From a technical standpoint, certain things (e.g., deeplinks) require you to own the domain and operate a Web site at that domain where you can control what that Web site serves.

From a practical standpoint, one imagines that your marketing, documentation, and support will be centered around your Web site.

Comment: Thanks! can I name my app's namespace  as `com.android.app` ?  Will Google Play refuse my  app with namespace `com.android.app` ?

Comment: @HelloCW: I do not work for Google and cannot speak to their trademark policies and whether those extend to application ID values.

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly Part of the listing criteria is a url to your privacy agreement for the app so you will need a website of some kind though i think, if you're making a public app

And you probably want to name your com stuff something specific to your app. Com.magicapp.app otherwise your app may look scammy.

Hope this helps!